# Matterport Mask RCNN TRAIN_ROI_PER_IMAGE explanation?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have been trying to train a breast cancer segmentation model with mask rcnn. I have been able to understand almost all the hyperparameter but this one variable `TRAIN_ROI_PER_IMAGE` I just can't seem to wrap my head around it and there's little to no documentation available for it.
If anyone could please explain it to me, it would be super helpful for my research.

Comment: Can you give some link (e.g. Github link) to the model, dataset, code, etc.?

Comment: sure, https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN this is the framework I use, the code and everything is same. I am implementing this research, https://second-look.github.io/

Comment: @KazimRaza it simply means, how many regions will be proposed to feed the classifier from the feature maps.

Comment: @M.Innat if you answer my question with this comment then I can mark it as the correct answer/ super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TRAIN_ROI_PER_IMAGE` - means how many Region of Interest or **ROI** proposals will be fed to the mask head or the classifier.

[image]
img_src : [Ren et al., 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01497.pdf)

Concretely, This setting is like the `batch size` for the second stage of the model.